# Memory game element creation code not working

Tags: javascript

```
const cardSet = ['fa fa-diamond','fa fa-diamond','fa fa fa-paper-plane- 
 o','fa fa-paper-plane-o','fafa-anchor','fa fa-anchor','fa fa-bolt','fa fa- 
 bolt','fa fa-cube','fa fa-cube','fa fa-leaf','fa fa-leaf','fa fa- 
  bicycle','fa fa-bicycle','fa fa-bomb','fa fa-bomb'];
    let cardsOpen=[];
  let cardsflipped = 0;
 const theDeck = document.querySelector('deck');

  window.onload=function(){
shuffle(cardSet);
for(let i; i<=cardSet.length;i++){
    let cards= document.createElement('li');
    cards.innerHTML='<i class="'+ cardSet[i] +'"></i>';
    cards.classList.add('card');
    theDeck.appendChild(cards);
```

Hello this is the javascript for a memory game.
This code is supposed to shuffle all the cards and create the elements on the DOM but for some reason it is not working.
Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Where’s the shuffle function? Also have you tried using console.log after every step to debug your own code and finding where the break is? For example in the for loop of the onload function do a console.log(“for loop running”); and see if the console sees it - if not, you know it hasn’t reached that loop. Also Posting us the full code as well doing some basic troubleshoot to point us in the direction of the “break” will help us provide you a good answer to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `shuffle` method works correctly, I can spot two errors in your code:

```js
const cardSet = ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fafa-anchor', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bomb'];
let cardsOpen = [];
let cardsflipped = 0;

// you probably meant #deck, unless you have a nonstandard <deck />
// element in your code. querySelector accepts a CSS-style selector,
// which is why it is called that.
const theDeck = document.querySelector('#deck');

window.onload = function() {
  shuffle(cardSet);
  
  // use let, and you have to assign i to 0
  // otherwise it will be undefined and undefined + 1 = NaN
  // and NaN + 1 = NaN so this loop will never terminate
  for (let i = 0; i <= cardSet.length; i++) {
    let cards = document.createElement('li');
    cards.innerHTML = '<i class="' + cardSet[i] + '"></i>';
    cards.classList.add('card');
    theDeck.appendChild(cards);
  }
}
```

Comment: Incrementing a `const`?

Comment: @Vasan oops, I'm used to iterating arrays using `for...of` loops.

Comment: thankyou very much it acctually worked i have forgotten to initialize i